# Filtering listview with SimpleCursorAdapter does not work

Tags: android, listview, filter, simplecursoradapter

I'm trying to filter a listview, that is connected to the database by a SimpleCursorAdapter. I read a lot of other questions on that topic but I can't get it to work. When I type in a word nothing is happening. I would be happy with the list filtering on button click too.
Does anyone know what the problem is?

relevant methods:

```
private void initListView() {
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
}

private void populateListView(){
    Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllItems();
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] {Database.COL_IMAGE, Database.COL_DATE, Database.COL_HEAD};
    int[] toViewIds = new int[] {R.id.list_view_image, R.id.list_view_date, R.id.list_view_headline};
    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.list_view_search, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIds, 0);
    listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}

private void initSearch() {
    cursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            String catchword = null;
            if(constraint!=null){
                catchword = constraint.toString();
            }
            return myDb.getWordMatches(catchword);
        }
    });

    searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_edit_text);
    searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            SimpleCursorAdapter filterAdapter = (SimpleCursorAdapter) listView.getAdapter();
            filterAdapter.getFilter().filter(editable.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

here is the relevant method from my database:

```
public Cursor getWordMatches(String query) {
    return database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {COL_DATE, COL_HEAD, COL_IMAGE, COL_MAP, COL_TEXT}, "COL_HEAD like ?", null, null, null, "%'"+ query +"'%");
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I could really need some help here...